# Gambas3 in English

Tags: language-support

I have Ubuntu 14.04 in Dutch.
When I install Gambas3, it's in (poor) Dutch too, but I want it to be in English, as examples, tutorials etc. are in English. 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can create the file `~/bin/gambas3` and give it this contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
exec /usr/bin/gambas3 $@
```

Make the file executable with:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/gambas3
```

Then, next time you log in, gambas3 should be started with English as the display language.